# Javascript in CakePHP

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp

I had one page in Views in CakePHP, it have normal javascript block,
Just inserted:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
---code---
</script>
```

Inside page, and it was all working okay...
But now... It doesn't show...
How can I change configuration or something to enable showing javascript blocks without CakePHP commands.
Javascript needs data from that page so I can't use outer file,
and it's too long to use $javascript->codeBlock

Is there any way to reconfigure stupid CakePHP to start showing those blocks?
Some files are showing javascript, and it's working all okay, but some of them won't show...

Please help...

Comment: can't understand why would a framework mess with that anyway ..

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "start showing those blocks". You want the code to be visible?

Comment: because site is already created in CakePHP, and I'm just re-designing it, and I need this block in this file... It was working before, so something is changed, and I don't know why... My friend is also working on this site, so it might be he who changed this...

Comment: Yes, I want code to be showed to users, javascript code, because now it just skip that block, it doesn't show when I open page in browser... Like there is no that block of javascript code...

Comment: well, noone will be able to help you unless you show some code.

Comment: Oh I think I see - you mean that you want to make sure the code in your template actually gets out to the client web browser ... makes sense now; I guess it's kind-of obvious :-)

Comment: It's not point in showing code... Because I try to add some words before and after that javascript block and words are showed, but content of javascript block won't show at all... I already show how block looks like, just with code inside... But nothing is showing, not even a start and end of block... It's just like CakePHP block javascript code in regular show...
Is something changed in configuration or where that file is called? Can that be done? Please help...

Comment: Cake is *not* stripping any Javascript out, you can rest assured of that. It's just PHP, and it's outputting whatever is in the view templates as-is. Your problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean that you want to *view* the code when the page is displayed, try surrounding it with `<pre>...</pre>`

If you mean you want the browser to *process* the code, then provided you are

1. actually going to that view file and
2. the code isn't commented out (`<!-- ... --> or <?php /* ?> ... <?php */ ?>` etc.) and
3. the code isn't being obliviated by a php conditional (if ... then ... else... endif)

then it will be there. Try Firefox ctrl-u to view the  source.

Also try posting the view code here so that we can give you some sort of informed solution.